# Issue upgrading from Jackson 1.9 to 2.5 using Spring 3.1.2 - ProviderBase class not found

Tags: json, spring, dependencies, jackson, jax-rs

I'm trying to upgrade a current project from Jackson 1.9 to 2.5.  Everything was going well until I tried to startup my WAS 7 server and receive this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error
>   loading class
>   [com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider] for bean
>   with name 'jaxbProvider' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-configuration.xml]: problem with
>   class file or dependent class; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase

This appears to be in relation to trying to register the Jackson Provider in my web.xml below:

```
<!-- Jackson Provider -->
<bean id="jaxbProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" >
    <property name="mapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" >
    <property name="annotationIntrospector" ref="jacksonAnnotationIntrospector"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonAnnotationIntrospector" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair" >
    <constructor-arg ref="primaryAnnotationIntrospector" />
    <constructor-arg ref="secondaryAnnotationIntrospector" />
</bean>

<bean id="primaryAnnotationIntrospector" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector" />
<bean id="secondaryAnnotationIntrospector" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector" />
```

I have the following jars on my classpath:

```
jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
jackson-core-2.5.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.5.0.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations.2.5.0.jar
```

Now from my understanding its looking for this fellow:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase
```

but can't find it.  A google search reveals that class as belonging to a

jackson-jaxrs-provider project, but I can't find a specific jar for that.  I think that's because that is just a base for the jackson-jaxrs-json-provider.2.5.0.jar that I already included.  So shouldn't it inherently be able to see that base class through the jackson-jaxrs-json-provider.2.5.0.jar??

If anyone has an idea of what could be wrong I would be very appreciative!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used Maven, adding `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` as a dependency, you will see all the following pulled in

[image]

<sub>(I had an image from another post with v2.2.3- disregard the version)</sub>

As you can see, it *does* depend on a `jackson-jaxrs-base`, which is where the `ProviderBase` is located.

You can download it [**here**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base) (just click the <kbd>2.5.0</kbd>, then the <kbd>Download Bundle</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation peeskillet.  This fixed my issue.  First of all I am not using Maven (I wish I could but my organization doesn't allow it), so I missed that `jackson-jaxrs-base` dependency.  Second, I was thinking that the dependency was on `jackson-jaxrs-providers` ([here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-providers)) instead, which was wrong.  Thanks for clearing up my confusion.  I no longer have the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase` error on startup!